# Dump audio metadata (album title, track number, etc.) to command line

Tags: linux, command-line, music

If I open an audio file with Audacity or Rhythmbox, for example, I can look at the metadata tags such as Artist Name, Track Title, Year, etc. .  Is there a convenient way to do this on the command line under Linux?

Comment: .wav metadata is poorly supported. I'd search for something to edit RIFF INFO if that's possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's a standard sort of tag, I believe [`exiftool`](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) should do the trick.

If it doesn't you'd likely need to find something else that dumps the format [that audacity uses](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=84775) (apparently info tags).

Comment: you can run exiftool in the command line as ```exiftool sample.mp3```

Answer (score 9):

You can use one of these tools:

## mediainfo

Simple program outputting all the basic information from audio files.

## exiftool (from package perl-image-exiftool)

This one is more customizable and supports reading and writing meta information in image, audio and video files.

## mutagen-inspect (from package mutagen)

Simple frontend to the mutagen audio tagging library for Python.

Comment: mediainfo worked. It can also export to JSON: `mediainfo --output=JSON file.mp3`

Answer (score 2):

Try the utility [`id3info`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/id3info.1.html) for MP3 files.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't print any info for the `.wav` files I exported from Audacity.

Comment: OK, I thought you were talking about `.mp3` files. I don't know about metadata in `.wav` files.